# Aws Cognito php client getUser allways is null

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

i'm trying to validate an access token isued by aws cognito on backend but i'm stucked at this, i have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Bridge;

class AwsCognitoClient
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(
        string $key,
        string $secret,
        string $poolId,
        string $clientId,
        string $clientSecret,
        string $region,
        string $version
    ) {
        $this->region = $region;
        $this->poolId = $poolId;
        $config = [
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $key,
                'secret' => $secret,
            ],
            'region' => $region,
            'version' => $version,
            'app_client_id' => $clientId,
            'app_client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'user_pool_id' => $poolId,
        ];
        $aws = new \Aws\Sdk($config);

        $this->client = $aws->createCognitoIdentityProvider();
    }

    public function verifyToken($access_token)
    {
        try {
            $user = $this->client->getUser([
                'AccessToken' => $access_token
            ]);
            error_log("USER NULL ALWAYS: " . json_encode($user));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log("ERROR COGNITO: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but $this->client->getUser always be empty and if token is expired throw correct exception for expired, but if token is valid not show nothing only $user be empty;
what is wrong?